# Cannot resolve symbol in Java

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and try to write an object to calculate the BMI of the human body.
But there is an error said that cannot resolve symbol `bmi` in the last return.

Want to know why the `bmi` returned in `getBMI()` cannot be used and what should I do for solving similar problems.

for the other question, is there any extra or missing stuff in my code?

```
    public class BMI {
        private double height;
        private double weight;
        private String name;

    public BMI(String name, double height, double weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public double getBMI(){
         double bmi = weight/(height*height);
         return bmi;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return name + " is " + height + "m tall and is " + weight + "Kg and has a BMI of " + bmi + "Kg/m^2";
    }
}
```

Comment: The scope of `bmi` is limited to only the method `getBMI()`. You can't access it outside the method.

Comment: You have two choices. Either compute bmi every time weight or height is set and have a bmi member of the class or call `getBMI` to calculate bmi each time it is needed. Your use case will dictate which of these is the optimal solution.

Comment: You have a method to calculate bmi, you need to use it in toString method.  `return name + " is " + height + "m tall and is " + weight + "Kg and has a BMI of " + getBMI() + "Kg/m^2";`

Answer (score 3):

`bmi` is not found in `toString()`. Try this,

```
public String toString(){
     return name + " is " + height + "m tall and is " + weight + "Kg and has a BMI of " + getBMI() + "Kg/m^2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable you declare in the method you can use it in the same method only, you can not use it anywhere outside that method, this concept is known as `scope`.
To understand this in the simplest way possible, try to find nearest upside "open parenthesis" `{` where ever you have declared the variable. and you can use that variable anywhere before that parenthesis is getting closed.

In your case you have declared `bmi` variable inside `getBMI()` method, so you can use that variable anywhere in that same method, but nowhere outside of it, and you are trying to use it in `toString()` method, where you can not access it, so you are getting an error

```
cannot resolve symbol bmi
```

To resolve this issue you can use anyone of following 2 approches

1] Call the `getBMI()` method in `toString()`
I'll recommend this approach because `getBMI()` is returning double, so lets take advantage of that and call it directly wherever you need to use the value of `bmi`.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
     return name + " is " + height + "m tall and is " + weight + "Kg and has a BMI of " + getBMI() + "Kg/m^2";
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per suggestion by Paul

2] Not so recommended in this scenario, but you can use this in many other scenarios, define global variable of `bmi` in the `BMI` class, later when you assign the value to it in constructor, you can use that variable anywhere in the same class, you can apply the formula in constructor itself. In this case your code will look something like this

```
public class BMI {
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private String name;
    private double bmi;

    public BMI(String name, double height, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.bmi = weight / (height * height);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " is " + height + "m tall and is " + weight + "Kg and has a BMI of " + bmi + "Kg/m^2";
    }
}
```

Comment: In this solution. You might as well compute the bmi in the constructor and sidestep the null issue, its value can be known then. Also should bmi be a string?

Comment: Yes, right. We can avoid to getting the null value.

Comment: Other thing to fix is make bmi a double.  It’s currently a string.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

```
public class BMI {
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private String name;
    private double bmi;

    public BMI(String name, double height, double weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.bmi = weight/(height*height);
    }

    public double getBMI(){
         return bmi;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return name + " is " + height + "m tall and is " + weight + "Kg and has a BMI of " + bmi + "Kg/m^2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a good solution but it might be improved with a little explanation.